# What do these coordinates mean: MW - VP101 3° 12' 43.2'' S 5° 12' 39.6'' W?

Tags: the-moon, coordinate

I have a jacket with a tag that bears the label:

```
MW - VP101
3° 12' 43.2'' S
5° 12' 39.6'' W
```

When I looked it up, I discovered that these are the coordinates of the crater [Mosting A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6sting_(crater)). However, I do not know what the letters at the top refer to. Does anybody know what they mean?

[image]

Comment: Who made the jacket?

Comment: The brand is "Denim & Flower".